# Address of the array name pointer and the first element of the array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, array-pointer

Is the address of the first element of the array and the address of the array name pointer is same in C programming?

And what if we create a pointer(p) to the first element(a[0]) of the array(a[5]) then the address of the pointer(p) , first element(a[0]) and the default pointer(a) will be same? `

As my conclusion and research the address of the first element(a[0]) and the address of the array name pointer(a) is same but the pointer(p) which I have created holds the address value of the first element of the array(a[5]) but its address is different.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"the array name pointer"_? Can you show it in code?

Comment: Please present actual code demonstrating what pointer values you are asking about.  Also, please do some searching around for yourself, because at least part of the question I *think* you are asking is already answered many times over here.

Comment: Related: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: My guess is that OP is referring to the decayed pointer that you get when you use the array's name.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “default pointer” but given:

`char buf[10];
char *p = buf;
char *q = &buf[0];`

`p` and `q` will be equal, both point to the first character in `buf`. A code example showing your “research” would be helpful.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That's possible. I hope OP will clarify it.

Comment: Given `SomeType array[10];`, the value of `&array` is of type `SomeType (*)[10]` and the type of `&array[0]` is `SomeType *` — these are (manifestly) not the same type.  However, the byte patterns of the two addresses are the same: `printf("%p %p\n", (void *)&array, (void *)&array[0]);` will print the same value.

Comment: @Mohd Saq, "Is the address of the first element of the array and the address of the array name pointer is same in C programming?" --> They have different types.  The 2 pointers have an _equivalent_ value.  They compare the same, yet may have a different bit pattern.